# ReferenceError: user is not defined. Passport and Google. User Schema already created

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, google-authentication

I found simmilar questions on the platform but the answers they are providing is creating user schema. Tat i have already done, maybe. Please help me out.

```
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
```

I am trying to authenticate users with google login, when i try to register with google an error like this appears

*ReferenceError: user is not defined.*

My app is like so:

```
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(session({
  secret: "we are on!",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(id, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      console.log("THE USER: ", user);
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The error points out to the user inside deserializeUser, i do not know how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, i was calling a user i never declared.
Here is the solved code, just the errored part

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

Comment: Inside the call back function i had declared id instead of user